# Rails 4 Unprocessable Entity Error when making ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to build an ajax object and I am getting a funny error...

Here are my nested form fields

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_item do |ff| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= ff.hidden_field :quote_id, value: @quote.id %>
        <%= ff.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: "Select Category", hide_label: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= ff.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.order(:name), :products, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true, hide_label: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= ff.submit "Add Item", class:"btn-u btn-u-blue pull-right", id:"add_item" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Here is my quote.js.coffee where I am making my ajax call

```
$('form').on 'click', '#add_item', (e) ->
e.preventDefault()
product = $('#quote_order_item_product_id :selected').val()
quote = $('#quote_order_item_quote_id').val()
console.log(product)
console.log(quote)
$.ajax '/order_items',
  type: 'POST'
  dataType: 'json'
  data: { order_item: { product_id: product, quote_id: quote } }
  success:(data) ->
    alert data.id
    return false
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    alert textStatus
    return false
```

Here is my controller (params accepts `product_id` and `quote_id`)

```
def create
@order_item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @order_item.save
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order_item }
  else
    format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Here is my order_item model as requested

```
belongs_to :quote
belongs_to :product
  # validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  before_save :set_quantity
  before_save :set_unit_price

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

  def set_unit_price
    product = Product.find(self.product_id)
    self.unit_price = product.price
  end

  def set_quantity
    if quantity.nil?
      self.quantity = 1
    end
  end

  private
  def product_present
    if product_id.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def quote_present
    if quote_num.nil?
      errors.add(:quote, "is not a valid quote.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

Here is my route

```
  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

I've also tried to make the data being posted in this format

```
data: { product_id: product, quote_id: quote }
```

Comment: It means that you have some validation errors Because `@order_item.save` returns `false`

Comment: Can u post yr console params ?

Comment: I added the model so you guys can review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have some validations in place, so you cannot save an empty object.

You are always trying to save an empty object because you are not initialising it with params from the request.

To keep to the rails convention send the params in the format you tried:

`order_item: { product_id: product, quote_id: quote }`

Then in your controller change your code to this

```
def create
 @order_item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @order_item.save
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order_item }
  else
    format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

private

def order_item_params
params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :quote_id)
end
```

Your problem was with this line 
`@order_item = OrderItem.new` which needed arguments (in rails it is advised to whitelist them hence the other method).

P.S. If it is still not working, please provide your validations for `OrderItem` model.

Comment: I added the validations from the model, now I am getting a different error stating that route http://localhost:3000/order_items - 404 Not Found.

Comment: So since I was calling the route '/order_items' from my quotes controller it was not finding the route. I created a route as follows `post 'quotes/:id/order_items' => 'order_items#create'` in my routes and it's all working. Appreciate your help!